# How to set parent Id in version 3 of google drive API?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I am currently using version2 of API. Now, I want to switch to version3. I want to set the parentId in this version. What changes should I make in below line of code to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this function was changed because it wasn't mentioned in the [Migration Guide for v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration). You can see the snippet here in [Inserting a file in a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder):

```
String folderId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E";
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
```